# Disable default SwipeRefreshLayout animation on refresh

Tags: android, android-studio, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I am using swiperefreshlayout for pulltorefresh. when user pulls down it shows loading animation **without calling `setRefreshing(true)`**.

**I want to show loading animation only when `setRefreshing(true)` is called.**

Is there any way to **disable** auto showing animation on pull of screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onCreate()` method : Try doing these

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });
```

When you want to re do refresh than use vice-versa.

**hope this helps.**

Comment: if u set     mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); then it will also the view inside destorying the purpose of swiperefresh

Comment: I have updated answer. Visibility will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```