# Disable MainActivity SwipeRefreshLayout from Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, expandablelistview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a main activity which includes a `SwipeRefreshLayout`. The activity contains `fragments`.

I would like to disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` from within a particular fragment, since the swipe gesture of the `SwipeRefreshLayout` is interfering with the scroll gesture of the `ExpandableListView` on the fragment.

For that, I have tried the following, without success:

on the Fragment I have:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container, false);

    //......
    expListView  = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
    final MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    //.......
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Log.d("test","Disabled");
            //SwipeRefreshLayout is called swipeRefreshLayout on MainActivity
            mainAct.swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });
```

After running this, I can see the Log message, so the `swipeRefreshLayout` should be set to **false**, however the pull-down gesture for the SwipeRefreshLayout is working

Comment: Post your activity code as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try like:

From your fragment (casting) :

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).disableSwipe();
```

Now in your activity:

```
private void disableSwipe(){
    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
}
```

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35789260/2826147) for more details

Comment: This should work, but I would instead prefer the way of using [delegation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, I assume by delegation you mean using an interface?, why would interface be better than this solution?, this one looks quite simple and with very few lines of code.

Comment: @Luca Nicoletti yes, i would say there are many solutions available but this is simple & easy solution

Comment: this will solve your issue @codeKiller and you can tell me if you are stuck

Comment: Even though this works for me, and I accept the answer, would like to know if there is any pro/con using this solution or delegation solutions

Comment: Yes, interfaces allows you to delegate a function to another class which has everything needed to perform the action. That's better for usability. As you might want to re-use the fragment in another situations, not attached to the `MainActivity`. The solution suggested will make your app crash. Instead, using a interface, the fragment can check if the `interface` is not null, and therefore call a method. Or even check if the interface is of the correct type.

Comment: @AmitVaghela yes, this work. But what about using the fragment in another activity? Crash.

Comment: ok i totally see your point, you are right, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @LucaNicoletti managing with flags as it will be done in interface also by implementing it.

Comment: @AmitVaghela actually, using interface you don't use flags. You just set the interface object inside the fragment from the activity or other objects that implements the interface. Inside the fragment you usually just do `if (interface != null) interface.methodCall()`.

Comment: but you have to implement that interface right ?@LucaNicoletti